# Inheritance for fields in java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble coming up with a better solution to the following problem. I'm supposed to use the visibility of "public Warrior warrior" in my aggressiveWarrior class which extends this parent abstract class. The professor tells me that the visibility being public is the key but I can't seem to figure out how to use it correctly. I need to return the attack level of this warrior where say if I test '10' I end up getting the default '3' that I set in the constructor. I have looked at other inheritance posts but I now seem to be even more confused on why what I have tried isnt working. I'm not allowed to change the Builder to a non static class because the tests wont work.

```
public class AggressiveWarrior extends Warrior {

    private int level;
    private int attack;
    private int defense;

    private AggressiveWarrior(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLevel() {
        return this.level;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAttack() {
        return this.attack;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDefense() {
        return this.defense;
    }
    
    
    public static class Builder extends Warrior.Builder{

        private AggressiveWarrior aggressiveWarrior;
        public Builder(int level) {

            aggressiveWarrior = new AggressiveWarrior(level);
            aggressiveWarrior.attack = 3;
            aggressiveWarrior.defense = 2;

        }
        
        public Warrior.Builder attack(int attack) {
             return this; // have tried return this.warrior.attack; 
        }
        public Warrior.Builder defense(int defense){
            return this;
            
        }
        public Warrior build(){
            return aggressiveWarrior;
        }
                
        
    }
    

}

public abstract class Warrior {

    public int level; 
    public int attack;
    public int defense;


    public abstract int getLevel();
    public abstract int getAttack();
    public abstract int getDefense();
    
    
    public static abstract class Builder{
        
    public Warrior warrior;
    
    public Builder attack(int attack) {
        warrior.attack = attack;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Builder defense(int defense) {
        warrior.defense = defense; 
        return this; 
    }
    
    public Warrior build() {
        validate(warrior);
        return warrior;
    }
    
    public void validate(Warrior warrior) {
        if (warrior.level <= 0 && warrior.attack > 0 && warrior.defense > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Level must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (warrior.defense <= 0 && warrior.attack > 0 && warrior.level > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Defense must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (warrior.attack <= 0 && warrior.defense > 0 && warrior.level > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Attack must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (warrior.attack <= 0 && warrior.level <= 0 && warrior.defense > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Level must be greater than 0. Attack must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (warrior.level <= 0 && warrior.defense <= 0 && warrior.attack > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Level must be greater than 0. Defense must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (warrior.attack <= 0 && warrior.defense <= 0 && warrior.level > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Attack must be greater than 0. Defense must be greater than 0. ");
        }

        else if (warrior.level <= 0 && warrior.defense <= 0 && warrior.attack <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Level must be greater than 0. Attack must be greater than 0. Defense must be greater than 0. ");
        }

    }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't re-declare the fields. Use getter methods from the parent (super) to access them.

Comment: (And ... despite what your teacher apparently says ... it is a bad idea to declare fields as `public`.)

Comment: Note also that the getter methods should not be abstract if the class has the fields

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare the fields already defined in parent class.

Please follow OOPs and for abstract class concepts you may refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

The code structure can be simplified and additionally the validate logic may be optimized.